# Autocompletion in jTextField and jTable

Tags: swing, jtable

I have an application in which i am trying to create autocompletion of jTextField and jTable from database values as we do in address bar of browsers. I tried many ways,but i couldnt complete it. Do any one know how to do this in a simple way, the links and notes which i had got was quite confusing for me. I am using java and MySQl in netbeans.Hoping a reply soon..

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give JIDE JIDE Common Layer at http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm a try. It is free and open source. There are two features you might be interested in. Both are in JIDE Common Layer. One is AutoCompletion feature which can auto-complete based on a known list while you are typing (no drop down). The other is IntelliHint feature which will show a list of matching choices in a drop down while you are typing. Since you mention something like address bar of a browser, I would recommend IntelliHint. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think it is you who just post our JIDE forum to ask for more helps. As I said, once you get the demo source code, it is very easy to figure out how to use it.
Say if you have a text field and an ArrayList of items to show up while typing, just do this to enable IntelliHint feature on the text field.

`ListDataIntelliHints intellihints = new ListDataIntelliHints(textField, list to show);`